# react-jsonschema-forms validator error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, react-jsonschema-forms

I'm trying to build dynamic forms using rjsf and having some issues with the validator.

The error message is applicable to any validation type attempt i.e. if a field is required or minLenght check.

If I disable noHtml5Validate={false} then I get a pop up telling me to populate required field. My goal is to display all errors and highlight relevant inputs in red.

[image]

This corresponds to this line in the code:

```
var property = instancePath.replace(/\//g, ".");
```

My schema is:

```
const testSchema = {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "account",
    ],
    "properties": {
        "reference": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua",
            "nullable": true,
        },
        "account": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "pattern":"^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$",
        }
    },

    "additionalProperties": false
};

import Form from "@rjsf/bootstrap-4";
import validator from "@rjsf/validator-ajv8";

return <>
    { schema && <Form 
        schema={testSchema}
        uiSchema={uiSchema}
        validator={validator}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        noHtml5Validate={true}
        formData={formData}
        onChange={(e)=> onChangeHandler(e.formData)}
    />}</>;
```

What is more confusing is that when I set up a new test app using npx create app and use the same settings it works just fine so I'm really unsure to resolve this issue. I've already spent 3 days searching for a solution